# Spark 1.4.1 dataframe queries on Hive ORC tables take forever

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, snappy, orc

I am using Apache Spark 1.4.1 (which is integrated with Hive 0.13.1) along
with Hadoop 2.7

I have created an ORC table with Snappy compression in Hive and inserted
around 50 million records into the same using Spark Dataframe API
(insertInto method),as below:

```
inputDF.write.format("orc").mode(SaveMode.Append).partitionBy("call_date","hour","batch_id").insertInto("MYTABLE")
```

This table has around 50-60 columns with 3 columns being varchar and all
other columns being either INT or FLOAT.

My problem is that when I query the table using below spark command:

```
var df1 = hiveContext.sql("select * from MYTABLE")
val count1 = df1.count()
```

The query doesn't come out and is stuck for several hours at the above
query.Spark console logs are stuck at below:

*16/12/02 00:50:46 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 2700 missing tasks from
ShuffleMapStage 70 (MapPartitionsRDD[553] at cache at
MYTABLE_LOAD.scala:498)16/12/02 00:50:46 INFO YarnScheduler: Adding task
set 70.0 with 2700 tasks*

The table has 2700 part files in warehouse directory.

I have tried coalescing the inputDF to 10 partitions before inserting into
the table which created 270 part files for the table instead of 2700,but
querying the table gives same issue,i.e. the query doesn't come out.

The strange thing is that when I invoke the same select query via
spark-shell(invoked with 5g driver memory),the query gives results in less
than a minute.

Even for other ORC tables (not Snappy compressed),querying them using
hiveContext.sql  with very simple queries (select  from table where ) is taking more than 10 minutes.

Can someone please advise what could be the issue here? I don't think there
is something wrong with the table as the spark-shell query wouldn't have
worked in that case.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Anyone got any suggestion on what could be the issue

Comment: Any reason to stick to 1.4.1? It's so old that I doubt you can find many people still *remembering* how it was back then. It's 2.0.2 days now. Upgrade!